# Automate processes on websites studying ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In two days I found myself thinking of automating processes through ajax requests on websites.
What I would like to do is to study some request from some operation executed on a website and replicate it with javascript.
So for example I have this POST request when I select some seats in a theater:
[image: some server post request]

But my knowledge on this topic is not enough, I know how to handle POST and GET requests but I don't know exactly how to replicate them.
So let's say we want to replicate this request with jquery, how it would be?

PS = I would really appreciate if you could post some resources about this topic.

Comment: [ReadTheDocs?](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: @cricket_007 almost every question posted here on stackoverflow can be answered with "Read the docs"... you're such a genius!

Comment: Not trying to be critical I'm just wondering what you have looked at and/or tried. You can see the form data and the headers using Chrome, so I imagine it would be straightforward.

Comment: _studying ajax req_ why/what study? like how many calls are made there?

Comment: @jai i would like to know how many calls are madre there, which paramater I have to pass, how to handle cookies etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I don't get you wrong, you can listen ajax requests and jQuery provides event related to ajax requests, for instance:

`ajaxComplete(callback)`
http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/

It provides you 3 parameters: `event, xhr, settings` and you can use them to reconstruct the ajax request.

Comment: It would be awesome, but the problem is that I don't have access to the pages so I cannot use any function

Comment: @GiacomoCerquone you can use tempermonkey chrome extension, which is used to execute your javascript code on the pages that you don't have control. Does this help?